# How to generate custom license for widevine DRM

Tags: encryption, video-processing, drm, widevine, bento4

I have been researching about DRM video encryption. All the example in internet I find it needs a lincense link, and a "X-AxDRM-Message" encrypted message as header request. But when I generate widevine encrypted video files with bento4, it don't provide me any sourse to generate the lincese link, it provides me KID and Key. What should I do with these two things? can I create the license link with php or python or js? or how can I get the link for free?

Comment: Did you managed to find a way to do it

Comment: You seems marked this ticket as resolved. could you please elaborate a bit you did? I'm interested too

Answer (score 1):

You need to either host the DRM service yourself or else use a DRM, or more likely, multi DRM, online service.

This will provide you with the keys, IV etc you need to encrypt and also with the license server URL that your clients need to call to request the license playback key.

Note that for some DRM schemes, PlayReady and FairPlay, the license server URL can be included in the video stream, but for Widevine it usually needs to be configured on the client separately.

Its useful to test online first if possible - there are multiple player sites that will allow you test DRM protected streams, including the open source Shaka Player demo:

- https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo

Comment: do you know any opensource project that could be helpful to setup such a license server? Im working on similar thing and getting stuck. for instance i tried this https://github.com/willkk/opendrm but i dont think it works with most common used drm like widevine or playready. what i really want know is how the request and response are formed? what they should contains? in which content type?

Comment: @irzhy - I am not aware on any open source DRM server other than openDRM you linked above